# How to access the Parent of the Source in a Drop Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am trying to handle some drag and drop functionality for values in my TreeView.
I am specifically targeting the Drop method. I want to be able to access the Parent object of the element being dragged.

The

```
TreeView.SelectedItem
```

is the property of the TreeView that I suspect I will need. However, this property is of type string, so accessing the Parent object is proposing a challenge.

I tried using the

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject)
```

method but there doesn't seem to exist a conversion from string to DependencyObject and vice versa.

I am able to access the ParentControl of the target, but not the source and I can't understand why.

This is my Drop Method, as well as the MouseMove. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 private void TreeViewItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TreeViewItem target)
        {
            string source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
            string dropTarget = target.DataContext as string;
            var parentControl = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((TreeViewItem)(sender));
            var parentElement = ((VirtualizingStackPanel)(parentControl)).DataContext;

            if (parentElement is GroupDecision decision)
            {
                if (decision.Decisions.Contains(source) && (decision.Decisions.Contains(dropTarget)))
                {
                    int sourceIndex = decision.Decisions.IndexOf(source);
                    int targetIndex = decision.Decisions.IndexOf(dropTarget);
                    SwapElements(sourceIndex, targetIndex, decision.Decisions);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!decision.Decisions.Contains(source))
                    {
                        decision.Decisions.Add(source);
                        // Remove from old

                    }
                }
            }
        }



 private void TreeViewItem_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (TreeView.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, TreeView.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is populated on a method called in the View Model's constructor.

Comment: It's a string. The parent of the TreeView.SelectedItem should be a GroupDecision.

Answer (score 0):

The treeview.selecteditem in your dodragdrop there is what ends up in your data when you do your e.Data.GetData.  Since you cast it to a string, it's just a string floating about in memory.  Adrift on an ocean of not-in-the-visual-tree. It has no parent control, because it's a string.
The sender is whatever control you dropped it on, so that's not the thing you dragged from. It's what you're dragging to.

But... what you pass as data can be whatever you give it.
That can be a simple string or a complicated business object with many properties on it.
Whatever you want when you drop, is best stashed away there in that data.
In the answer here:
[WPF drag and drop and data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727391/wpf-drag-and-drop-and-data-types)
That's a viewmodel.

I don't really follow what you want out of this but instead of

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, TreeView.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

You should put whatever is required as that second parameter.

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, AmoreComplexObjectWithMoreData, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Define a class which has properties matching whatever you need. New it up and set those as you start dragging.  When you drop, you have everything you need then.  Cast your drag data back to said class.

Answer (score 0):

A `string` has no visual ancestor. Maybe you want to pass the `TreeViewItem` container of the selected item to the `DoDragDrop` method?:

```
private void TreeViewItem_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        if (TreeView.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this,
                TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(TreeView.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem,
                DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then get a reference to the visual container in the `Drop` event handler and traverse the visual tree as you like:

```
TreeViewItem source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeViewItem)) as TreeViewItem;
string sourceObject = source.DataContext as string;
//...
```

Comment: This seems to crash the program immediately on a drag.

Comment: Please provide a repo that includes code to populate the TreeView with sample data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.